# WindowBuilder Pro for Eclipse?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to install WindowBuilder Pro for Eclipse Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) from the address:[Installing WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html)
However it says:
"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found."

Has anyone successfully installed this recent copy of WindowBuilder Pro, or should I look for some other visual UI builder for Eclipse?

Comment: [for example](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/3.7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindowBuilder has been donated to the Eclipse Foundation, and is now one of the Eclipse projects. I followed instructions on http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/installation/updatesite_3.7.html and all worked well.

Edit: mKorbel's link is probably a better place because it is all on Eclipse's website. :)

Comment: What do you mean by mKorbel's link? and when did you last install it successfully? all the links (including http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7) get forwarded to same page!!